# Oracle помогите оптимизировать запрос

Tags: база-данных, oracle, оптимизация

Люди добрые, помогите! По работе столкнулся с такой проблемой, есть такой запрос:

```
select /*+ USE_HASH(nsi_core_gr) */
kategoria,works,oper,
time_mmm,
sum(ratio) over(PARTITION BY kategoria,works,oper order by kategoria,works,oper rows unbounded preceding) sval_rows
from (
select /*+ USE_HASH(nsi_core_gr) */
d.work as works,d.kategoria,
d.oper,
d.time_mmm,
ratio_to_report(count(d.time_mmm)) OVER (PARTITION BY d.kategoria,d.work,d.oper) AS ratio    
from nsi_data d
inner join nsi_core_gr crg on crg.id_gr=d.work_gr and crg.id_core=21
where d.date_zagr between to_date('01.1.2016','dd.mm.yyyy') and to_date('30.3.2016','dd.mm.yyyy')            
and d.proc_od=9
group by d.kategoria,d.work,d.oper,d.time_mmm
order by d.kategoria,d.work,d.oper,d.time_mmm
)
```

Таблица nsi_data содержит более 10 млн строк, таблица nsi_core_gr содержит около 2000 строк. Без inner join запрос выполняется приемлемое количество времени, с inner время увеличивается чуть-ли не в 10 раз, что недопустимо, но без inner не обойтись так как иногда нужна будет выборка с ним.
Plan hash value: 1412621496

план выполнения с inner

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                          | Name          | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                   |               | 46767 |  2968K|       | 43128   (1)| 00:08:38 |
|   1 |  WINDOW NOSORT                     |               | 46767 |  2968K|       | 43128   (1)| 00:08:38 |
|   2 |   VIEW                             |               | 46767 |  2968K|       | 43128   (1)| 00:08:38 |
|   3 |    WINDOW BUFFER                   |               | 46767 |  1689K|       | 43128   (1)| 00:08:38 |
|   4 |     SORT GROUP BY                  |               | 46767 |  1689K|  2592K| 43128   (1)| 00:08:38 |
|   5 |      NESTED LOOPS                  |               | 46767 |  1689K|       | 42672   (1)| 00:08:33 |
|   6 |       NESTED LOOPS                 |               | 46767 |  1689K|       | 42672   (1)| 00:08:33 |
|   7 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | NSI_CORE_GR   |    50 |   350 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |         BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWIDS|               |       |       |       |            |          |
|*  9 |          BITMAP INDEX SINGLE VALUE | C_GR_IND      |       |       |       |            |          |
|  10 |        BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWIDS |               |       |       |       |            |          |
|  11 |         BITMAP AND                 |               |       |       |       |            |          |
|* 12 |          BITMAP INDEX SINGLE VALUE | W_GR_INDEX    |       |       |       |            |          |
|* 13 |          BITMAP INDEX SINGLE VALUE | P_OD_INDEX    |       |       |       |            |          |
|* 14 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | NSI_DATA |   935 | 28050 |       | 42672   (1)| 00:08:33 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                         
---------------------------------------------------                                                         

   9 - access("CRG"."ID_CORE"=21)                                                                           
  12 - access("CRG"."ID_GR"="D"."WORK_GR")                                                                  
  13 - access("D"."PROC_OD"=9)                                                                              
  14 - filter("D"."DATE_ZAGR"<=TO_DATE(' 2016-03-30 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND                
              "D"."DATE_ZAGR">=TO_DATE(' 2016-01-01 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
```

План выполнения без inner

```
Plan hash value: 719937189                                                                          

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
| Id  | Operation             | Name          | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |               |  1800K|   111M|       |   345K  (1)| 01:09:04 |     
|   1 |  WINDOW NOSORT        |               |  1800K|   111M|       |   345K  (1)| 01:09:04 |     
|   2 |   VIEW                |               |  1800K|   111M|       |   345K  (1)| 01:09:04 |     
|   3 |    WINDOW BUFFER      |               |  1800K|    44M|       |   345K  (1)| 01:09:04 |     
|   4 |     SORT GROUP BY     |               |  1800K|    44M|    76M|   345K  (1)| 01:09:04 |     
|*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL| NSI_DATA |  1800K|    44M|       |   331K  (1)| 01:06:24 |     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                 
---------------------------------------------------                                                 

   5 - filter("D"."DATE_ZAGR"<=TO_DATE(' 2016-03-30 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd                         
              hh24:mi:ss') AND "D"."PROC_OD"=9 AND "D"."DATE_ZAGR">=TO_DATE(' 2016-01-01 00:00:00', 
              'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
```

hint-ы как видно не работают...как мне кажется, помогите пожалуйста, я нуб в оптимизации. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: 1. По date_zagr индекс есть (хотя не думаю что поможет, но вдруг).  2. Попробуйте условие соединение написать как `on crg.id_gr=nvl(d.work_gr,0)` может вернется к FULL. Хотя FULL в вашем "хорошем" варианте мне то же не особо нравится, но из двух зол ...

Comment: Попробуй в хинт поставить алиас а не имя таблицы:  /*+ leading (crg d) use_hash (crg d) */

Comment: @SkyWalker вынесешь свой комментарий в ответ, чтобы автор отметил его как правильный и закрыл вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй в хинт поставить алиас, а не имя таблицы:

```
/*+ leading (crg d) use_hash (crg d) */
```